# Square when pie jqplot is 100%

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I am using **jqplot** for drawing a pie chart. But when I draw a pie chart with data that represent 100% of a variable, it shows a very strange pie chart.

[image]

This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataHighlight', 
        function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) 
        {
            $('#info1').html('' + data[0] + " - " + data[1] );
        }
    );

    $('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataUnhighlight', 
        function (ev) {
            $('#info1').html('&nbsp;');
        }
    ); 


    var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('chart1', [data],
    { 
        title: {
            text: '',   // title for the plot,
            show: true,
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
            padding: 0,
            color:"#FFFFFF",    
            shadow: false,
            rendererOptions: {
              dataLabelFormatString: "<font color=white>%d%</font>",
              diameter: 135,
              showDataLabels: true, 
              sliceMargin: 1, 
              textColor: "#ABBBBB",
              lineWidth: 5
            },

        }, 
        legend: {
            show:true, location: 'e'
        },

        grid: {
            background: '#ffffff',
            shadow: false,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    }

  );
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think you are not going to get much answers if you have not explained it well. Normally readers assume that all the details about the question is on the post body itself and doesn't try to take half from the title and other half from the post body and to understand the question. At least include the code you have used for doing this.

Comment: What is the content of "data" array?

Comment: it is tooltip, like Android - 123 devices

Comment: I wanted to know the value of variable in this line. "jQuery.jqplot ('chart1', [data]" I don't think it is a tool tip. See the doc: http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html  and also check whether the below additional comma issue is the reason.

Comment: this is data -- data = [[' Android', 3]  ];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is

> sliceMargin: 1,

without it all works ok.

Answer (score 0):

You have two extra commas in

```
title: {
            text: '',   // title for the plot,
            show: true,
        },
```

and in

```
        rendererOptions: {
          dataLabelFormatString: "<font color=white>%d%</font>",
          diameter: 135,
          showDataLabels: true, 
          sliceMargin: 1, 
          textColor: "#ABBBBB",
          lineWidth: 5
        },
```

That is invalid in javascript. Therefore the reason for this issue could be this.